# Switch class on tabs with React.js

Tags: class, backbone.js, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs

So I have a `tab-component` that has 3 items:

```
React.DOM.ul( className: 'nav navbar-nav', 
    MenuItem( uid: 'home')
    MenuItem( uid: 'about')
    MenuItem( uid: 'contact)
)
```

And in the `.render` of `MenuItem`:

```
React.DOM.li( id : @props.uid, className: @activeClass, onClick: @handleClick,
    React.DOM.a( href: "#"+@props.uid, @props.uid)
)
```

Every time I click an item, a backbone router gets called, which will then call the `tab-component`, which in turn will call a `page-component`.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the fact there's basically a one-way data-flow. And I'm so used to manipulating the DOM directly.

What I want to do, is add the `.active` class to the tab clicked, and make sure it gets removed from the inactive ones.

I know the CSS trick where you can use a `data-` attribute and apply different styling to the attribute that is `true` or `false`.

The backbone router already has already gotten the variable `uid` and calls the right page. I'm just not sure how to best toggle the classes between tabs, because only one can be active at the same time.

Now I could keep some record of which tab is and was selected, and toggle them etc. But React.js already has this record-keeping functionality.

The `@handleClick` you see, I don't even want to use, because the router should tell the `tab-component` which one to give the `className: '.active'` And I want to avoid jQuery, because React.js doesn't need direct DOM manipulation.

I've tried some things with @state but I know for sure there is a really elegant way to achieve this fairly simple, I think I watched some presentation or video of someone doing it.

I'm really have to get used to and change my mindset towards thinking React-ively.

Just looking for a best practice way, I could solve it in a really ugly and bulky way, but I like React.js because it's so simple.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Push the state as high up the component hierarchy as possible and work on the immutable `props` at all levels below. It seems to make sense to store the active tab in your `tab-component` and to generate the menu items off data (`this.props` in this case) to reduce code duplication:

**Working JSFiddle of the below example + a Backbone Router:** http://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/4G46g/

```
var TabComponent = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      menuItems: [
        {uid: 'home'},
        {uid: 'about'},
        {uid: 'contact'}
      ]
    };
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      activeMenuItemUid: 'home'
    };
  },

  setActiveMenuItem: function(uid) {
    this.setState({activeMenuItemUid: uid});
  },

  render: function() {
    var menuItems = this.props.menuItems.map(function(menuItem) {
      return (
        MenuItem({
          active: (this.state.activeMenuItemUid === menuItem.uid),
          key: menuItem.uid,
          onSelect: this.setActiveMenuItem,
          uid: menuItem.uid
        })
      );
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      React.DOM.ul({className: 'nav navbar-nav'}, menuItems)
    );
  }
});
```

The MenuItem could do very little aside from append a class name and expose a click event:

```
var MenuItem = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSelect(this.props.uid);
  },
  render: function() {
    var className = this.props.active ? 'active' : null;

    return (
      React.DOM.li({className: className},
        React.DOM.a({href: "#" + this.props.uid, onClick: this.handleClick})
      )
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved a lot for me, however, I'm dealing with a router, and it seems that calling: `React.renderComponent( TabComponent( uid: 'home' ) )`, when the URL changes, triggers a series of components that shouldn't fire ate all in reacts' logic. Read the comments on: http://jsfiddle.net/TrySpace/9a7TA/2/

Comment: But the technical part, the: `this.props.active ? 'active' : null;` and `active: (this.state.activeMenuItemUid === menuItem.uid)` did the trick really, such simple expressions...

Comment: You are able to call [`setProps`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setprops) on the root component rendered with `React.renderComponent` calls. On routes changes, you can set the new active tab by calling `setProps`. In my example I made the active menu item part of the state, but it could be moved to props to make this possible.

Comment: To be clear, the `.bind()` part makes sure that either `props` or `state` are updated on their bound component? So for that it technically doesn't matter if I would use `props` or `state`? It only matters at which moment in the lifecycle I want to be able to access them. (but surely it would be best to divide `state` and `props` funtionally.) And one last thing: `setProps` and `setState` both  trigger the same components' lifecycles?

Comment: So the main issue I'm dealing with is, the `onClick` triggers the update, but when I manually edit the url it won't trigger a click. So I need the router to tell which tab to select, not the `onClick`

Comment: I added a Backbone Router in a working JSFiddle. Try clicking the tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/4G46g/

Comment: `classSet` is depricated. Could you update your fiddle? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html

Comment: @thedanotto Done. It's now using React 0.14.7, ReactDOM, and Babel (instead of the old JSX Transformer).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [react-router-active-componet](https://github.com/insin/react-router-active-component) - if you working with boostrap navbars.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to push the menu item click handler up to it's parent component. In fact I am trying to do something similar to what you are doing.. I have a top level menubar component that I want to use a menubar model to render the menu bar and items. Other components can contribute to the top level menubar by adding to the menubar model... simply adding the top level menu, the submenuitem, and click handler (which is in the component adding the menu). The top level component would then render the menubar UI and when anything is clicked, it would use the "callback" component click handler to call to. By using a menu model, I can add things like css styles for actice/mouseover/inactive, etc, as well as icons and such. The top level menubar component can then decide how to render the items, including mouse overs, clicks, etc. At least I think it can.. still working on it as I am new to ReactJS myself.