# how to manage active state in bootstrap navbar in react?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I know that the active class has to be managed manually in bootstrap. I have done that a few times with jQuery.

My newest project works with react though.

I know that I am not supposed to set classes in the dom with jQuery when using react. But how would this be done correctly?

Comment: well, sorry for the duplicate - but to be honest, I didn't understand the answer in that other post. In contrast I understand both answers from Jeremy D and PhInside, so what the hell...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You simply have to specify the `active` value of the tabs in your `render` function.
To know whether or not a tab should have a value for the the `className` property is to store it somewhere.

How do you store something in a react component? You use `state`.
You haven't shown any code but you could simply keep track of which tab is currently active in your state.

You could for example have this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return { activeTabClassName: "tab1" };
}

render: function() {
    return (
        <ul>
            <li className={(this.state.activeTabClassName === "tab1") ? "active" : ""}></li>
            <li className={(this.state.activeTabClassName === "tab2") ? "active" : ""}></li>className            </ul>
    );
}
```

**Warning:** This code block is just one example and isn't tested. (There are several ways to do it).

You could also check this: [Switch class on tabs with React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461129/switch-class-on-tabs-with-react-js)

Comment: very nicely explained - I got it: passed the name of the active nav as state, then set className when rendering. Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh yea, this is exactly what I was looking for !! React is awesome till now..

Answer (score 4):

You could use [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) to automatically or manually manage active state in bootstrap navbar.

Comment: I definitely will try that solution too, thanks a lot!