# How to handle .active state in React-Bootstrap's Nav NavItem, with React-Router

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I'm using using React with `react-router 2.0.0-rc4`, `react-bootstrap 0.28.2`, and `react-router-bootstrap 0.20.1`. I have the nav bar mostly working with the following structure, but the `.active` class is not applied correctly:

```
  <Navbar>
    <Nav activeKey={ this.state.selectedKey } onSelect={ this._onSelect } >
      <LinkContainer to="/">
        <NavItem eventKey={1}>Home</NavItem>
      </LinkContainer>
      <LinkContainer to="/login">
        <NavItem eventKey={2}>Login</NavItem>
      </LinkContainer>
      ...
    </Nav>
  </Navbar>
```

The problem is that the `.active` class is not unset as I move between the menu items. So, if I click NavItem 2, both items become active (no matter what `this.state.selectedKey` is set to). I have a larger menu and all nav items get set as active when any menu item is clicked. What am I missing?

I do not think this Q is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376922/how-to-manage-active-state-in-bootstrap-navbar-in-react) because the React-Bootstrap components are supposed to manage the active state automatically via the `activeKey` prop, but.. the docs do not show a clear example of this, so, confused :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your routes look like

```
<Route path="/">
  <Route path="login" />
</Route>
```

Then you'll want to use `<IndexLinkContainer>` rather than `<LinkContainer>` for the `to="/"` link.

Answer (score 2):

With `<LinkContainer>`, there's no need for the `eventKey`, so it can be removed. Doing so will have the `active` handled properly.

So you end up with

```html
  <Navbar>
    <Nav>
      <LinkContainer to="/">
        <NavItem>Home</NavItem>
      </LinkContainer>
      <LinkContainer to="/login">
        <NavItem>Login</NavItem>
      </LinkContainer>
      ...
    </Nav>
  </Navbar>
```