# ReactJS active NavLink

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, reactstrap

I want to know how could I control the className of a Navlink so if the actual path is X, then the class of a NavLink is active. I did it before using Laravel and simple bootstrap but I dont know how to do this with React and Reactstrap.

Example Laravel:

```
<a href="{!!URL::to('link1')!!}" class="{{Request::is('link1') ? 'activeMenu' : '' }} >Link1</a>
```

My ReactJS code:

```
  <Nav className="navbar-logged">
    <NavItem>
      <NavLink className="nav-link-gdc" href="/">HOME</NavLink>
      <NavLink className="nav-link-gdc" href="#">LINK1</NavLink>
      <NavLink className="nav-link-gdc" href="#">LINK2</NavLink>
      <NavLink className="nav-link-gdc" href="#">LINK3</NavLink>
      <NavLink className="nav-link-gdc" href="#">LINK4</NavLink>
    </NavItem>
  </Nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you are using react-router

Just add your path in `to` argument, rather than in `href`. Like this:

```
`<NavLink className="nav-link-gdc" to="/">HOME</NavLink>`
```

And it will add class `active` automatically. See [the docs for `NavLink`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md)

### If not and that NavLink is from reactstrap

Then you will have to add some router logic to be able to mark nav link as active or, if you don't need changing urls in address bar, make something like [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376922/how-to-manage-active-state-in-bootstrap-navbar-in-react)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using react-router and when I try to use to="/" the link doesn't work and the class is not active. Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Be sure to import `NavLink` from `react-router` and not from `reactstrap`. Apart from that, inspect it in Chrome with  React Developer Tools and go from there.

Comment: The problem is that this only works when I reload the view but not when I clicked in a NavLink to change the route.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, we can control the class name of the NavLink:-

```
 const pathName = this.props.history.location.pathname;
 <NavLink to='/pathNameHome' className='header__route--link'
    activeClassName={pathName === '/home || pathName === '/dashborad' ? 'header__route--active' : ''} >
```

> In above code 'pathName' we are taking from the history location, if you
>   want to put condition on pathName then you can also do that {pathName ===
>   '/home || pathName === '/dashborad' ? 'header__route--active' : ''} in
>   this block we are comparing the path , if you want directly then you
>   can write  activeClassName= 'header__route--active' so once the path
>   is selected the class name 'header__route--active will activate else the class name header__route--link will be activated by default.