# React Communication Between Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing an architecture problem when trying this with React. I want to toggle tabs in the most reusable way using React JS.

So, ideally, I am looking for a way, in which on clicking on TabHeading, I deactivate the other TabHeadings in the TabHeader heading and also activate the corresponding TabPane (from this.props.target) in TabContent.

```
$(".tab-pane").hide();
$(React.findDOMNode(this.props.target)).show();
```

I want to avoid the solution above. I dont want to use classNames anywhere, or passing the parent component as a prop.Angular has $parent or somekind of variable to call functions on the parent right? Is there a similar way without explicitly passing the parent? Is there a way to communicate with siblings?  Please help.

```
<Tabs>
    <TabHeader>
        <TabHeading active="active" target={self.refs.pane1}>
            Heading 1
        </TabHeading>
        <TabHeading target={self.refs.pane2}>
            Heading 2
        </TabHeading>
    </TabHeader>
    <TabContent>
        <TabPane active="active" ref="pane1">
            Pane 1
        </TabPane>
            <TabPane ref="pane2">
               Pane 2
            </TabPane>
    </TabContent>
</Tabs>
```

**JS File**

```
var React = require("react");
var $ = require("jquery");

var TabHeader = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="tab-header">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var TabHeading = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount : function(){

    },
    handleClick : function(e){
         //something to set siblings to inactive
         //this.props.active="active";
         // this.props.target.props.active = "active";

    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="tab-heading" onClick={this.handleClick} >
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var TabContent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="tab-content">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var TabPane = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount:function(){
        console.log(this.props.children);
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="tab-pane">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var Tabs = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount:function(){

    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="tabs">
            {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
Tabs.TabHeader = TabHeader;
Tabs.TabHeading = TabHeading;
Tabs.TabContent = TabContent;
Tabs.TabPane = TabPane;

module.exports = Tabs;
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35sja49a/1/)

Comment: it would help if you put your code into a jsbin/jsfiddle/codepen so we can hack it to get to the answer :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22461129/368697 might answer your question. It's also about maintaining tab state with React components.

Comment: @ssorallen : Cool Answer. But, I need to add custom HTML which would be tough if I went with that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer without Flux. Please feel free to suggest ways to improve it.

**Tabs.js**

```
var React = require("react");
var $ = require("jquery");


var TabHeading = React.createClass({

render : function(){
        var view  ;

        return (
                <div onClick={this.props.handleClick} className={this.props.active? "active tab-heading" : "tab-heading"}>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>      
            );
    }   
 });



var TabPane = React.createClass({
render : function(){

        return (
            <div className={this.props.active? "active tab-pane" : "tab-pane"}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            );
    }   
});

var Tabs = React.createClass({

handleClick:function(){
    this.props.active = arguments[0];
    this.forceUpdate();
},
render : function(){
    var self = this;
    console.log("rendering");
    var tabHeadings = this.props.tabHeadings.map(function(item,index){
         active = (index==self.props.active);
         return <TabHeading key={index} handleClick={self.handleClick.bind(self,index)} index={index} active={active}>{item}</TabHeading>
    });
    var tabPanes= self.props.tabPanes.map(function(item,index){
         active = (index==self.props.active);
         return <TabPane key={index} active={active}>{item}</TabPane>

    });

    return (
                <div className="tab">
                    <div className="tab-header">
                            {tabHeadings}
                    </div>
                    <div className="tab-content">
                            {tabPanes}
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
}
});

module.exports = Tabs;
```

**File.js**

```
render:function(){

    var self = this;

    var tabHeading1 = (
            <p> Heading 1 </p>
        );
    var tabHeading2 = (
            <p> Heading 2 </p>
        );
    var tabPane1 = (
            <p> Pane 1 </p>
        );
    var tabPane2 = (
            <p> Pane 2 </p>
        );
    var tabHeadings = [tabHeading1,tabHeading2];
    var tabPanes = [tabPane1,tabPane2];

    return (<div>
            <div className="container">
                <Tabs tabHeadings={tabHeadings} tabPanes={tabPanes} active="0"/>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
}
```

JSFIDDLE - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3cLwkmev/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to using Flux? An awful lot of tricky things with React alone become quite simple when you combine Flux with React.

In this case, a `store` would keep track of the active tab. Clicking on an inactive tab would notify the store that a new tab should become active. All of your individual tabs would subscribe to the store so that when the store changed the state of the active tab, all the siblings would be notified.

Comment: Yeah, open to that as well. Working on it. If you can come up with a piece of code, that would be awesome. Thanks!